# How to make Users have different properties depending on their Role (ASP.NET Identity)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Let's say there's two types of users:

1- Seller
2- Buyer

Each type will have properties unique to them. Following this analogy, buyers  would have something like a cart and sellers would have an inventory. Buyers have no need to have and inventory and so on.

When defining my implementation of IdentityUser,

a) should it have ALL the properties (indifferent if is going to be a buyer or a seller) and limit the access to properties depending on the role of the user with authentication?

b) or, is there a way for roles to have properties of their own?

I'm asking this because my intuition is telling me that having empty fields in the database (i.e. sellers have nothing to do with cart items so why should there be empty fields or a table with this relationship) is a bad way of going with this.

> Note. I'm currently using .NET Framework but, if the best (or simpler) answer is on .NET Core, I have no problem upgrading as this is a new project.

> Edit. The real app is not about sellers and buyers, is more bit more complicated than that. Doesn't seems right to expand on that as the core problem is having two kinds of users, and each interact with the app in almost completely different ways. If someone is a user of type 1, they can't ask to become one of type 2, they must register a new account.

Comment: I don't think IdentityUser would support table-per-hierarchy, but you could add Buyer / Seller tables with a 1-1 FK.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Yeah, I was thinking something like that but it felt like working around Identity and not with it... But I'll probably end up doing it, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

There are no obvious problems with your design. A user can apply to become a seller, which lead to a role change.

If your business is more complicated, you can design the seller table separately. When a user applies to become a seller, he can be a new user or a buyer. When the user has already registered as a buyer, just copy the existing identity to the seller form and fill in additional information.

Comment: I don't want users who sign up as buyers to just ask to become sellers (the app is not really a marketplace, I used the seller/buyer analogy to better explain my problem). If a seller/buyer wants to become a buyer/seller, they need to register with a different account. Sorry if this omission muddled the question.